# django decide which language template based on user ip

Tags: python, django

in my views.py,I have different languages templates to show.
I want to decide this based on the user's ip when user first come in,
How can I do this? 
Which keywords should I google?
Please guide me ,thank you very much!

views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.GET.get("lan", None):
        lan = request.GET['lan']
        if lan == 'en':
            return render(request, 'english/index.html',)
    return render(request, 'chinese/index.html',)
```

and in my template/chinese/index.html :

```
 <a href="{% url 'core:index' %}?lan=en">
```

Comment: So you want to get the location(country region) of user ip ?

Comment: No, you should not try to do this. How do you expect the IP to relate to the desired language? Think about highly linguistically mixed countries. And what if the user is simply visiting another country? You should use the standard method of determining language, which is the `Accept-Language` header.

Comment: could you offer me a website or tutorial on internet,I'm still not understand

Comment: Try to use [Local middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.locale)

Answer (score 0):

Use GeoIP databases, and any python module providing bindings to it.
Some good ones are :

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GeoIP/

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygeoip/